# Post via Ajax chega vazio ao PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho alguns valores selecionados por checkboxes que eu gostaria de enviar para serem processados em outro script PHP.

Quando envio o post via ajax para uma página que recebe a variável $_POST e a imprime, só visualizo "Array (0){}".

```
var objeto = {flag: "exportar"};
var arr = [];
var seletores = document.querySelectorAll(".meusCheckBoxes");
for(i = 0; i < seletores.length; i++){
  if(seletores[i].checked){
    arr.push(seletores[i]); 
  }
}
objeto['dados'] = arr;
$.ajax({
  url: "Url",
  data: objeto,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(retorno){
    $(".conteudo").html(retorno); //array(0) { } 
    console.log(objeto); //Object {flag: "exportar", dados: Array[5]}
  }
});
```

Penso que o problema seja o fato de enviar um Object com um array dentro, pois quando envio separado consigo visualizar o retorno.

Preciso enviar um Object porque o índice ("exportar", nesse caso) tem que ser associativo, coisa que o array no javascript não possui.

Obs.: Perceba que no "success" o console imprime o Object com o array corretamente postado.

Comment: Já tentou enviar um JSON ao invés do array?

Comment: Sera que no lugar de arr.push(seletores[i]) não deveria ser algo como arr.push(seletores[i].value) ou checked?..porque tenho a impressão que só seletores[i] não vai mandar informação nenhuma.

Comment: @AdanRibeiro, se você está usando `contentType` e `processData` igual a false, então no lugar de enviar um Array, tente enviar um [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: @DungaCardoso desta forma como estou usando ele atribui a "arr" um input.all com todos os parâmetros que eu preciso. Veja o print abaixo.

![imagem ilustrativa](http://www.insomnia.net.br/vetores.jpg)

Comment: @AndreCardoso Já sim, mas por alguma razão não fui bem sucedido também.

Comment: @TobyMosque Não usei o FormData nesse exemplo simplesmente porque o layout ao qual eu estava buscando as informações não "facilitava" o uso dessa ferramenta. Mas é algo que posso tentar. Postarei aqui o resultado.

Comment: Obrigado @TobyMosque. Sua sugestão foi ótima.

Answer (score 1):

O PHP somente pega o value do objeto, no caso você está enviando um objeto para o php, onde o mesmo não irá reconhecer o objeto que está recebendo. Utilize:

```
arr.push(seletores[i].value);
```

E envie com o ajax com o JSON, pois é mais fácil de se trabalhar com ele.

Comment: Depois de tantos anos trabalhando com PHP, voltar aqui e ver essa dúvida mostra o quanto eu estava cru naquela época.

Answer (score 1):

Após o comentário do **@TobyMosque** sugerindo o uso do *FormData*, além de acrescentar um **form** no HTML fiz as seguintes modificações no meu JS:

```
/*var objeto = {flag: "exportar"};
var arr = [];
var seletores = document.querySelectorAll(".all");
for(i = 0; i < seletores.length; i++){
  if(seletores[i].checked){
    arr.push(seletores[i]); 
  }
}
objeto['dados'] = arr;*/

var objeto = new FormData(document.querySelector(".meuForm"));
objeto.append("flag", "exportar");

$.ajax({
  url: "URL",
  data: objeto,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(retorno){
    $(".conteudo").html(retorno);
    console.log(objeto);
  }
});
```

E ficou totalmente OK!

O problema inicial não foi exatamente resolvido, mas essa solução se mostrou melhor que a minha inicial. Grato a todos!